# Why does this stored procedure not return the correct ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Intermittently this stored procedure will return an ID that is in the millions when it should actually only be around 400.

```
set ANSI_NULLS OFF
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestStoredProcedure]
(
    @Title VARCHAR(50),
    @ID INT OUTPUT
)
AS

DECLARE @ResultsTable Table(InsertedID INT);

INSERT INTO Table 
(
    Title
)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @ResultsTable
VALUES 
(
    @Title
);
SELECT @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 InsertedID FROM @ResultsTable);
```

This stored procedure used to return the ID by using SCOPE_IDENTITY() but that had the same issue.

There are no triggers in the database. There are only the indexes on the primary keys that SQL Server creates automatically. There are no tables at all that have an ID anywhere near as large as what is being returned so I have no idea where these large numbers are coming from.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
As I said above, this stored procedure originally used SCOPE_IDENTITY() like so:

```
set ANSI_NULLS OFF
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestStoredProcedure]
(
    @Title VARCHAR(50),
    @ID INT OUTPUT
)
AS

INSERT INTO Table 
(
    Title
)
VALUES 
(
    @Title
);
SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

**Edit 2:**
The exact SQL version is:
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4230.00 (X64)   Jul 30 2009 13:42:21   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

**Edit 3:**
This is how the stored procedure is being called (good old classic ASP, it's a legacy site)

```
set obj_CMD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    with obj_CMD
        .ActiveConnection = Application("DSN")
        .CommandText = "TestStoredProcedure"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

        dim txt_title
        txt_title = "Some text"

        set oParam = .CreateParameter("@Title",adVarChar,adParamInput,50,txt_title)
        .Parameters.Append oParam       
        set oParam = .CreateParameter("@ID",adInteger,adParamOutput)
        .Parameters.Append oParam
        .Execute

        dim ID
        ID = .Parameters("@ID").Value

    end with
set obj_CMD = nothing
```

**Edit 4:**
Running DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Table') returns:

Checking identity information: current identity value '422', current column value '422'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

This is as expected.

Comment: I've never been a fan of 'top 1'. Do you get the same issues if you use max(InertedID) instead?

Comment: Pretty sure the `@ResultsTable` is overkill - should be able to set the `@ID` in the OUTPUT clause

Comment: In Table do you have a timestamp for when the insert happened?  If so, you can SELECT TOP 1 AutoGeneratedID FROM Table ORDER BY timestampcolumn DESC

Comment: Which edition of SQL 2005 (run `select @@version`)

Comment: @mpenrow - that's not safe in a multiuser environment

Comment: @James Wiseman I have implemented the MAX method instead of the TOP 1. Being an intermittent issue, I will need to wait and see if it fixes it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is how you execute your sp.

```
declare @i int = 0

EXEC [TestStoredProcedure] '1', @i OUTPUT

select @i
```

Maybe you forget the OUTPUT keyword...

EDIT: And if it so - use SCOPE_IDENTITY() because this is better way to get the id value in your case.

Comment: The error is intermittent so there is nothing major missing like the output keyword. I was using SCOPE_IDENTITY() when the error first occurred and changed it to the code in the question as an attempted work around

Comment: Try to execute DBCC CHECKIDENT, maybe you'll get some additional info

Comment: Maybe this could help - 

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that it is not possible to determine the value assigned to an identity column until after the row has been created, and that includes trying to access it via the OUTPUT clause.

@@identity and scope_identity() really should work. Can you post your samples using that code?

(A side-note: when I say "my understanding is...", I mean that I've looked into this a *lot* over several versions of SQL Server, and I've never found a way to do this, and moreover I seem to recall reading a few posts and articles over the years that say it flat-out cannot be done, but hey, I would really like to be wrong, so I'll watch this post.)

Comment: You can access the new IDENTITY value using the OUTPUT clause. But yes, SCOPE_IDENTITY() should do the job.

Comment: I've never had an issue returning identities using this method - the `inserted` table in the `OUTPUT` clause reflects the inserted row just as in a trigger - see the MS documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx.

Comment: I know that when 2005 first came out I read somewhere that the output parameter did not catch identity columns. Perhaps I read it wrong, perhaps they wrote it wrong, perhaps they've since fixed it.